# preg_match displaying nothing/Unknown modifier 'I'

Tags: php, html, preg-match

i have a question about preg_match.
I have a textfield, where users can fill in random text. However when they type:

> [IMG]image url here[/IMG]

i want everything between [IMG][/IMG] to be put in a variable.

What i have now:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_signature_table'])){
    $string = $_POST['thread_message'];
    echo $string;

    if (preg_match('/[IMG](.*?)[/IMG]/', $string, $display)) {
        print_r($display);
    }else{
        echo "[IMG][/IMG] was not used.";   
    }
}
```

When i post something in the form and press submit. i get the result i just filled in. (done by echo $string).

But. i always get this result:

```
This is typed in the textfield. and contains [IMG]an image[/IMG] 
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'I' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proeven\Forum\profile.php on line 124 
[IMG][/IMG] was not used.
```

As you can see. The first line is me result from $string.

Then i get an error (line is at if(preg_match))

And then it goes to the else statement.

However in my result, you can see that i used [IMG][/IMG] and i expect the result to be: **an image**

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

***EDIT:***

people downvoting and saying it is a duplicate.

I looked at other peoples questions about this, but still did not know how to solve my problem.

People downvoting. Please tell me why... The question is clear enough i think.

Comment: Escape the `[` and `/` -> `\[`, `\/IMG` - `'/\[IMG](.*?)\[\/IMG]/'`

Comment: Might be a duplicate but saw that and still did not know what to do :/ Also people downvoting. Please tell me why. Explanation was clear enough i think. And yes i watched other questions and searched the internet. But still did not know what to do.

Comment: It is clear what to do: escape special characters and pattern characters that are used as regex delimiters.

Comment: Since this is the first time i'm using pregmatch i did not know that. Also a lot of questions are getting marked as duplicate. In the future no one will be able to ask a question beause everything has been asked already before. Even though some people (like me) don't know what to do even when seeing an other answer. Little but unfair or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your regex in order for it to work.

`preg_match('/[IMG](.*?)[/IMG]/', $string, $display)`

becomes

`preg_match('/\[IMG\](.*?)\[\/IMG\]/', $string, $display)`

you can also easily try your regex on different inputs here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: This did it for me.. can't belive it was this haha but would never have thought about this

Comment: Thats what this community is about :) Please also accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Need to wait 6 minutes will accept then :)